# how to convert multiple mysql column string to date

Tags: mysql

please i have a `modified_by` column in mysql table with string like this `"40,1280825613|40,1280825617"`. the `"40"` is the id of the user that made changes to the record and `"1280825613"` is the date string. The `|` separates different periods of change.

How do i change the entire column to a readable date without affecting the user id. either mysql or php solution is welcome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a PHP script. You'll need to make two columns `modified_by` to retain the user id and `modified` for the timestamp. If there are multiple `modified_by` for each record you'll probably want to make a separate table, i.e. `revisions`. This would be the best way to store the data relationship. I'd also recommend not storing formatted data. You should already see why that's not a good idea. The database is the *raw* data, use PHP to format it.

Once you have that setup, just:

1. Select the data from the old table.
2. Loop over the records
3. `explode()` the column on `|`
4. Loop over the array
5. `explode()` the element on `,`
6. Insert into new columns/table

Forgive me, but I'd rather *teach you how to fish*.

Comment: wow, thats super fast. thank you for the suggestion. will try that pending other suggestion. thank you once again